# Azure Data Factory 'Data Flow' time conversion for multiple Date Formats using Derived Column

Tags: azure, datetime, timestamp, azure-data-factory

The development is in ***Azure Data Factory -- Data Flow***

1. I am getting an input file with various columns and one column with DateFormat **('MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss')**.
2. I am trying to convert the above DateFormat to **toTimestamp('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')**
3. I have tried with the below format in **Derived Column** tab on the particular column needed in sink below is the Expression used to convert such case.
   **`iifNull(toTimestamp(<string_column_name>,'MM/dd/yyyy\'T\'HH:mm:ss'), toTimestamp(<string_column_name>,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'))`**
4. For reference i am attaching the sample Date format got in the input file **`01/26/2018 00:00:00`**.
5. Ref 4, should be converted to the format as **`2018-01-26 00:00:00`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of date `01/26/2018 00:00:00` you provided is `'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'` which isn't contained in your expression. This leads to you got Null. If your column also has 'MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss' and 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' format, you can try this expression:

```
iifNull(toTimestamp(<string_column_name>,'MM/dd/yyyy\'T\'HH:mm:ss'), toTimestamp(<string_column_name>,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),toTimestamp(<string_column_name>,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
```

Data preview:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much it worked in my situation in Data Flow.